# Ошибка при установке APCu на Debian

Tags: php, debian

При проверке php -v после установки APCu выдает ошибку:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'apcu.so' (tried: /opt/php73/lib/php/modules/apcu.so (/opt/php73/lib/php/modules/apcu.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor), /opt/php73/lib/php/modules/apcu.so.so (/opt/php73/lib/php/modules/apcu.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```